# .ics and meeting forward notifications

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar, ical4j

I'm no calendar expert and I need some help in figuring out how to make use of some outlook functionalities with my code-generate .ics.

I'm using java library ical4j to create my ics and so far I'm able to show the organizer and the attendees the calendar notification and make it automatically create an event (in the calendar). When the participant selects "accept" the organizer receives a notification.

So far so good and this is my generated ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170414T173633Z
DTSTART:20170414T080000
DTEND:20170415T180000
SUMMARY:Test Outlook 2
SUMMARY:This is a nice description
TZID:Europe/London
UID: XXXX
SEQUENCE:0
ORGANIZER;CN=Smart Workshop:MAILTO:testing@test.com
DESCRIPTION:This is a nice description
LOCATION:asd
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=Attendee tester-cal4rev2:mailto:tester-cal4rev2@outlook.it
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=Attendee aodocs-user:mailto:testing@test.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I now have two problem:

first, the organizer doesn't receive a notification if the event/email is forwarded to other people, this should be the "meeting forward notification"

second, outlook usually shows for the organizer a list of who has accepted or refused the invitation, seems like this is missing for my ics generated meeting.

Is it possible to achive these functionality by changing the .ics in some way ? I didn't find anything about this in the standard.

thank you everyone for the help